# OLEDB ExecuteNonQuery Error while inserting values to excel sheet

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am getting error message while inserting the values to Excel(error Message: Number of query values and destination fields are not the same). Do anyone can help me to fix this error. Target for this code is to get the values from sql database and inserting it to Excel.

//CODE

```
string sheetname = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            int s = 1, w = 0;
            string ssss = "";

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlapp = new  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlapp.Visible = true;
            xlapp.Workbooks.Open(@"\\server\planet\CalculationDatabase\Database.xls");
            string path = @"\\server\planet\CalculationDatabase\Database.xls";
            string path1 = @"\\server\planet\CalculationDatabase\Settings.xlsx";
            string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES""";
            string con1 = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path1 + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES""";
            OleDbConnection cn2 = new OleDbConnection(con1);
            cn2.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("select * from [" + sheetname.ToString() + "$]", cn2);
            OleDbDataReader rd2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (rd2.Read())
            {
                ssss = rd2["Info Name"].ToString();
                if (ssss.ToString() == "")
                {
                    w = int.Parse(s.ToString());
                    break;
                }
                s++;

            }
            rd2.Close();
            cn2.Close();
            var queries = string.Join(",", (Enumerable.Range(1, w).Select(i => "ip" + i)));       
            SqlConnection con3 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=173.83.250.71,1433; Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog=paradigm;User Id=sa; password=Paradigm123");
            con3.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("select  " + queries.ToString() + "  from paradigm.dbo.pinput where tempsheet='" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'", con3);

            SqlDataReader rd3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
            OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(con);
            cn.Open();

            while (rd3.Read())
            {

                var queries1 = string.Join(",", (Enumerable.Range(0, w - 1).Select(i => "'" + float.Parse(rd3[i].ToString()) + "'")));

                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();//I am getting error here
            }
            rd3.Close();
            con3.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Hope for you that the password, user and ip are not real

Comment: And now, we should guess where the error happens?

Answer (score 0):

The error occured since the connection string for .xls file is different. 
Replace OLEDB connection "con" with

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;
Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";

Comment: Sorry but this is not an answer you must edit your question and add the error part you should not add it here in the answer section